# What does the Spirit Ring do in the Castle in the Darkness prologue?

Tags: castle-in-the-darkness

Castle In The Darkness has a Prologue segment that can be unlocked by dying 10 times.  In this prologue, there's a secret Spirit Ring that you can collect.  It causes the player character to have a white spectral-looking figure constantly follow and mirror all his moves, but near as I can tell, the effect is just visual.

Is there any benefit to wearing the Spirit Ring, or is it just a neat visual effect?

Answer (score -1):

> **[On the steam forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/262960/discussions/0/618453594747488282/),"FIRE_KEEPER" posts:**
>
> Well now its too late : P i got them all. The 2 spelunky characters, ***the life steal item the spirit ring*** the world of sin ( ending goal 2 ) Just wanted to know do i need those in the same gameplay to get to goal 2.

I can not confirm, myself, but you will want to confirm what happens when you attack an enemy *with only the Spirit Ring equipped* and with preferably *a good chunk of health missing*. It appears the ring provides **Life Steal**, which should mean that when you attack an enemy, you will heal some of your health, relative to the amount of damage you deal.

Comment: Nope.  The life steal item is entirely separate from the Spirit Ring.  I got that item, and the Spirit Ring is not it.